# Почему htaccess перезапускает страницу несколько раз?

Tags: php, .htaccess

имею вот такой .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
#Удаляем www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#Удаляем index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Убираем слеш / в конце строки
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#из http в https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#любая ссылка отправляет на index
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

на странице код, каждое обновление страницы записываю в БД +1

```
$param= mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM setting WHERE `id` = '1'")); 
$param_new= $param['numeral'] + 1;
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE setting SET `numeral` = '$param_new' WHERE `id` = '1'");
```

В итоге после каждой перезагрузки страницы, имею 6 ее запусков.
не поможете сделать чтоб был всего один? куда смотреть куда капать? заранее спасибо

Comment: откройте в браузере панель разработчика и на вкладке Сеть посмотрите, что у вас происходит. Если есть перенправления какие-то циклические, то ваш вопрос имеет место быть, иначе мб у вас этот запрос инклудится по 6 раз просто, или еще чего-то.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вставить этот блок сразу после `RewriteEngine on`:

```
 Предотвратить ошибку, связанную с бесконечным внутренним редиректом
# (Internal redirection: mapping an URL to another in the same virtual host)
# ->>>
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
# <<<-
```

Это должно помочь для вашего случая.

Comment: эх, не помогло...